# Use the original matrix to get a couple of new matrices

Tags: r

I have a matrix which is made up of 4 columns (i.e. column 1, column 2, column 3 and column 4)

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1
3  1 -1 -1 -1
4  1 -1 -1 -1
5  2  1  1 -1
6  2  1  1 -1
7  2 -1 -1  1
8  2 -1 -1  1
9  3  1 -1  1
10 3  1 -1  1
11 3 -1  1 -1
12 3 -1  1 -1
13 4  1 -1 -1
14 4  1 -1 -1
15 4 -1  1  1
16 4 -1  1  1
```

My question is: I want to use this 4 columns to get 3 new matrices.
These matrices are made of the following columns:  `12, 13, 14, 23, 24, 34, 123, 124, 134, 234, 1234.`
Here I use 12 to represent `column 1 * column 2`.

The first matrix has 6 columns:  `12, 13, 14, 23, 24, 34`

```
    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 
1    1  1  1  1  1  1  
2    1  1  1  1  1  1  
3   -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  
4   -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  
5    2  2 -2  1 -1 -1 
6    2  2 -2  1 -1 -1  
7   -2 -2  2  1 -1 -1  
8   -2 -2  2  1 -1 -1  
9    3 -3  3 -1  1 -1 
10   3 -3  3 -1  1 -1 
11  -3  3 -3 -1  1 -1 
12  -3  3 -3 -1  1 -1 
13   4 -4 -4 -1 -1  1 
14   4 -4 -4 -1 -1  1 
15  -4  4  4 -1 -1  1 
16  -4  4  4 -1 -1  1
```

The second matrix has 4 columns: `123, 124, 134, 234`
And the last matrix has one column: `1234`

Does anyone have some simple pieces of code to do this? Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a small function to achieve this task ( assuming the same type of notation the OP used in his post )

```
create_prodmat <- function(mat, cols) {

index <- lapply(strsplit(cols, ""), as.numeric)

res <- do.call("cbind",
               lapply(index, function(i) apply(mat[, i, drop = FALSE], 1, prod))
               )
colnames(res) <- cols
res

}



mat <- matrix(rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 4), ncol = 3)
mat

##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    2    3
## [2,]    1    2    3
## [3,]    1    2    3
## [4,]    1    2    3


cols1 <- c("12", "13", "23")
cols2 <- "13"

create_prodmat(mat, cols1)

##      12 13 23
## [1,]  2  3  6
## [2,]  2  3  6
## [3,]  2  3  6
## [4,]  2  3  6


create_prodmat(mat, cols2)

##        13
## [1,]    3
## [2,]    3
## [3,]    3
## [4,]    3
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your data frame is named `dat`. If I understand your problem correctly you can do the following

```
A1 <- as.matrix(dat[,c(1,2,2,3)] * dat[,c(4,3,4,4)])
A2 <- as.matrix(dat[,c(1,1,1,2)] * dat[,c(2,2,3,3)] * dat[,c(3,4,4,4)])
A3 <- as.matrix(dat[,1] * dat[,2] * dat[,3] * dat[,4])
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it.
I broke it down line by line so it should be easy to follow.  Please let me know if you need it explained.

```
newColumns <- "14, 23, 24, 34, 123, 124, 134, 234, 1234"

splat1 <- strsplit(newColumns, ", ")[[1]]

splat <- strsplit(splat1, "")

splat <- lapply(splat, as.numeric)

results <- sapply(splat, function(cols) apply(master.matrix[, cols, drop=FALSE], 1, prod))

first <- results[, 1:4]
second <- results[, 5:8]
third <- results[, 9, drop=FALSE]

first; second; third

         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
  1     1    1    1    1
  2     1    1    1    1
  3    -1    1    1    1
  4    -1    1    1    1
  5    -2    1   -1   -1
  6    -2    1   -1   -1
  7     2    1   -1   -1
  8     2    1   -1   -1
  9     3   -1    1   -1
  10    3   -1    1   -1
  11   -3   -1    1   -1
  12   -3   -1    1   -1
  13   -4   -1   -1    1
  14   -4   -1   -1    1
  15    4   -1   -1    1
  16    4   -1   -1    1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
  1     1    1    1    1
  2     1    1    1    1
  3     1    1    1   -1
  4     1    1    1   -1
  5     2   -2   -2   -1
  6     2   -2   -2   -1
  7     2   -2   -2    1
  8     2   -2   -2    1
  9    -3    3   -3   -1
  10   -3    3   -3   -1
  11   -3    3   -3    1
  12   -3    3   -3    1
  13   -4   -4    4    1
  14   -4   -4    4    1
  15   -4   -4    4   -1
  16   -4   -4    4   -1
     [,1]
  1     1
  2     1
  3    -1
  4    -1
  5    -2
  6    -2
  7     2
  8     2
  9    -3
  10   -3
  11    3
  12    3
  13    4
  14    4
  15   -4
  16   -4
```

Comment: When OP said "column1 * column2" I think he wants the product of the column 1 and 2 but may be I'm wrong

Comment: @Stacy this doesn't do what your question asked?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I edited my columns to `12, 13, 14, 23, 24, 34, 123, 124, 134, 234, 1234.`
So the newColumns should be
 <- `12, 13, 14, 23, 24, 34, 123, 124, 134, 234, 1234`
Thanks for your help. :)